# How to calculate the possible number of sub-string that are palindrome. But substring that are unique?

Tags: c++, templates

```
    template <class T>
    int subPalindrome(T s)
    {
        int res = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; (j + i) < str.length() && (i - j) >= 0; j++)
            {
                if (str[i + j] != str[i - j])
                {
                    break;
                }
                else res++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; (j + i + 1) < str.length() && i - j >= 0; j++)
            {
                if (str[i + j + 1] != str[i - j])
                {
                    break;
                }
                else res++;
    
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

/*I have to write a program that takes a string as input and calculate the possible number of sub-string that are palindrome. But substring that are unique. I have implemented the logic of obtaining the number of all possible substrings but I don't know how to return a count of substrings that are unique

Comment: I am confused why this is a template function and why you don't use the `s` parameter but use `str` which is not declared.

Comment: Typing mistake " int subPalindrome(T s)" is supposed to be  "int subPalindrome(T str)"

Comment: You can use `std::unordered_set` to count only unique strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int subPalindrome(T s)
{
    
    int n = s.size();
    // dp array to store whether a substring is palindrome
    // or not using dynamic programming we can solve this
    // in O(N^2)
    // dp[i][j] will be true (1) if substring (i, j) is
    // palindrome else false (0)
    vector<vector<bool> > dp(n, vector<bool>(n, false));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // base case every char is palindrome
        dp[i][i] = 1;
        // check for every substring of length 2
        if (i < n && s[i] == s[i + 1]) {
            dp[i][i + 1] = 1;
        }
    }
    // check every substring of length greater than 2 for
    // palindrome
    for (int len = 3; len <= n; len++) {
        for (int i = 0; i + len - 1 < n; i++) {
            if (s[i] == s[i + (len - 1)]
                && dp[i + 1][i + (len - 1) - 1]) {
                dp[i][i + (len - 1)] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    //*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
    // here we will apply kmp algorithm for substrings
    // starting from i = 0 to n-1 when we will find prefix
    // and suffix of a substring to be equal and it is
    // palindrome we will make dp[i][j] for that suffix to be
    // false which means it is already added in the prefix
    // and we should not count it anymore.
    vector<int> kmp(n, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // starting kmp for every i form 0 to n-1
        int j = 0, k = 1;
        while (k + i < n) {
            if (s[j + i] == s[k + i]) {
                // make suffix to be false
                // if this suffix is palindrome then it is
                // already included in prefix
                dp[k + i - j][k + i] = false;
                kmp[k++] = ++j;
            }
            else if (j > 0) {
                j = kmp[j - 1];
            }
            else {
                kmp[k++] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    //*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        string str;
        for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
            str += s[j];
            if (dp[i][j]) {
                // count number of resultant distinct
                // substrings and print  that substring
                count++;
                
            }
        }
    }
    return count;

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your questions, a simple solution would be to store the detected palindrome strings into a container that preserve only unique values (e.g., std::set or std::unordered_set), and return it's size.

If you have access to std::unordered_set, it should be faster than std::set. Otherwise, and if performance is an issue, consider adding your string to a std::vector, and call std::sort / std::unique on it at the end. Adding to std::set is O(log(size)). As always, do not try to optimize your code without a good benchmark.

Note :

- You example could be made simpler by not using a template.
- As the input string is not modified, consider using a `const reference` to avoid a copy
- Also, you could turn the too (very similar) for-loops into functions.